# Python How to pick a character that can change from a string

Tags: python

If I have this string   `"for[4t]"`   and I want to pick `"4"`. *But the number can change*: the string can be `"for[12t]"`, `"for[342424t]"`, ect.. how I pick this number?

**I can't use `str.replace('for[', '').replace('t]')`, because the rest of the string after this can change.**

Comment: Is the pattern always the same? Like it’s always `for[NUMBERt]`? Will there only be a single number? Do you only want a single digit or the whole number?

Comment: @wkl yes, the pattern is the same, the number can have any number

Comment: Find the first `[` within the string.  Starting with the next character after that, get all of the digits.  Stop when you reach a non-digit.

Comment: @JohnGordon yes,I had already figured it out, but how can I do that?

Comment: you only want to extract number after x string ??

Answer (score 2):

You can get the variable with a regular expression. In this example, "for[" and "t]" are constant, and you want a variable number of digits inside. In a regular expression, `[` is a special character so needs to be escaped. `()` selects a group of characters you want to capture, and `\d+` says "any number of digits (but at least one)".

```
>>> import re
>>> test = "for[4t]"
>>> re.match(r"for\[(\d+)t]", test).group(1)
'4'
>>> test = "for[342424t]"
>>> re.match(r"for\[(\d+)t]", test).group(1)
'342424'
>>> test = "for[342424t] and other stuff"
>>> re.match(r"for\[(\d+)t]", test).group(1)
'342424'
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to do it

```
import re

strings = ["for[4t]", "for[12t]", "for[342424t]"]
for string in strings:        
    print(re.findall(r"for\[([0-9]+)t", string)[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# define some sample message
message = "hello for[555t] goodbye"

# find the first [
bracket_location = message.find("[")

# declare a variable for picking the number
pick_number = ''

# loop over the contents of message, starting one character past
# the bracket
for ch in message[bracket_location+1:]:
    # if this is not a digit, break the loop
    if not ch.isdigit():
        break

    # add this digit to the pick number
    pick_number += ch

# we're done, print the number we picked
print(pick_number)
```

Answer (score 0):

lets say the variable string holds the string, and the variable number will hold the number that you want.

if you wat number to have type string:

`number = string[string.index("[")+1:string.index("t]")]`

if you want number to have type integer:

`number = int(string[string.index("[")+1:string.index("t]")])`

This only works if the number is between `[` and `t]`, and if those are the first two instances of `[` and `t]` in the string